# C++ game programming help. Super-Simple

Tags: c++, prototype

I am in a bit of a jam. I am building a game, and for some odd reason, I cannot call on variables from one class to another. it was only in this specific section of code in which it does not work, so any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance:

here's the code:

```
class HeadsUpDisplay
{
private:
    int frame;
public:
    SDL_Rect HealthBar[20];
    SDL_Rect offset;
    void init();
    void render();
}HUD;

void HeadsUpDisplay::init(){
    offset.x = SCREENW*.9;
    offset.y = SCREENH/10;
    HealthBar[0].x = 0;
    HealthBar[0].y = 0;
    HealthBar[0].w = 204;
    HealthBar[0].h = 14;

    HealthBar[1].x = 204*1;
    HealthBar[1].y = 0;
    HealthBar[1].w = 204;
    HealthBar[1].h = 14;

    HealthBar[2].x = 204*2;
    HealthBar[2].y = 0;
    HealthBar[2].w = 204;
    HealthBar[2].h = 14;

    HealthBar[3].x = 204*3;
    HealthBar[3].y = 0;
    HealthBar[3].w = 204;
    HealthBar[3].h = 14;

    HealthBar[4].x = 204*4;
    HealthBar[4].y = 0;
    HealthBar[4].w = 204;
    HealthBar[4].h = 14;

    HealthBar[5].x = 204*5;
    HealthBar[5].y = 0;
    HealthBar[5].w = 204;
    HealthBar[5].h = 14;

    HealthBar[6].x = 204*6;
    HealthBar[6].y = 0;
    HealthBar[6].w = 204;
    HealthBar[6].h = 14;

    HealthBar[7].x = 204*7;
    HealthBar[7].y = 0;
    HealthBar[7].w = 204;
    HealthBar[7].h = 14;

    HealthBar[8].x = 204*8;
    HealthBar[8].y = 0;
    HealthBar[8].w = 204;
    HealthBar[8].h = 14;

    HealthBar[9].x = 204*9;
    HealthBar[9].y = 0;
    HealthBar[9].w = 204;
    HealthBar[9].h = 14;

    HealthBar[10].x = 204*10;
    HealthBar[10].y = 0;
    HealthBar[10].w = 204;
    HealthBar[10].h = 14;

    HealthBar[11].x = 204*11;
    HealthBar[11].y = 0;
    HealthBar[11].w = 204;
    HealthBar[11].h = 14;

    HealthBar[12].x = 204*12;
    HealthBar[12].y = 0;
    HealthBar[12].w = 204;
    HealthBar[12].h = 14;

    HealthBar[13].x = 204*13;
    HealthBar[13].y = 0;
    HealthBar[13].w = 204;
    HealthBar[13].h = 14;

    HealthBar[14].x = 204*14;
    HealthBar[14].y = 0;
    HealthBar[14].w = 204;
    HealthBar[14].h = 14;

    HealthBar[15].x = 204*15;
    HealthBar[15].y = 0;
    HealthBar[15].w = 204;
    HealthBar[15].h = 14;

    HealthBar[16].x = 204*16;
    HealthBar[16].y = 0;
    HealthBar[16].w = 204;
    HealthBar[16].h = 14;

    HealthBar[17].x = 204*17;
    HealthBar[17].y = 0;
    HealthBar[17].w = 204;
    HealthBar[17].h = 14;

    HealthBar[18].x = 204*18;
    HealthBar[18].y = 0;
    HealthBar[18].w = 204;
    HealthBar[18].h = 14;

    HealthBar[19].x = 204*19;
    HealthBar[19].y = 0;
    HealthBar[19].w = 204;
    HealthBar[19].h = 14;

}

void HeadsUpDisplay::render(){


    if(character.characterhealth >95 && character.characterhealth <= 100)
    {
        frame = 19;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >90 && character.characterhealth <=95)
    {
        frame = 18;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >85 && character.characterhealth <= 90)
    {
        frame = 17;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >80 && character.characterhealth <= 85)
    {
        frame = 16;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >75 && character.characterhealth <= 80)
    {
        frame = 15;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >70 && character.characterhealth <= 75)
    {
        frame = 14;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >65 && character.characterhealth <= 70)
    {
        frame = 13;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >60 && character.characterhealth <= 65)
    {
        frame = 12;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >55 && character.characterhealth <= 60)
    {
        frame = 11;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >50 && character.characterhealth <= 55)
    {
        frame = 10;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >45 && character.characterhealth <= 50)
    {
        frame = 9;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >40 && character.characterhealth <= 45)
    {
        frame = 8;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >35 && character.characterhealth <= 40)
    {
        frame = 7;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >30 && character.characterhealth <= 35)
    {
        frame = 6;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >25 && character.characterhealth <= 30)
    {
        frame = 5;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >20 && character.characterhealth <= 25)
    {
        frame = 4;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >15 && character.characterhealth <= 20)
    {
        frame = 3;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >10 && character.characterhealth <= 15)
    {
        frame = 2;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >5 && character.characterhealth <= 10)
    {
        frame = 1;
    }
    if(character.characterhealth >0 && character.characterhealth <= 5)
    {
        frame = 0;
    }
    SDL_BlitSurface(health, &HealthBar[frame], screen, &offset);
}
```

so the problem is, in each if statement, I get the error "erro: 'character' was not declared in this scope"; I tried to prototype the class too, which did not solve the problem. I appreciate any help, even negative feedback, at least it is something.

Comment: Well, `character` *isn't* declared in that scope.  Or anywhere else in your example, for that matter.  Where is it declared and what's it supposed to be?

Comment: I have no idea what you're doing here other than making a gigantic mess. Have you heard of `for` loops? How about doing basic math to establish the frame number? How about `frame = character.characterHealth / 5`?

Comment: it is the object of the players class. I dont know crap about inheritance, and I dont really know how to "Declare it"

Comment: @MatthewPigram: And how exactly is this related to his question?

Comment: Some feedback: 1) Be consistent in your capitalization of names so you can tell what's a variable, what's a type and what's a function. 2) prefix member variable names with "m_" so you can see at a glance, hey that's a class member, 3) `if(character.characterhealth >95 && character.characterhealth <= 100)` then can `(character.characterhealth >90 && character.characterhealth <=95)` be true too? Cause your code always tests. One word: `else`; 4) You can assign a struct like this: `m_healthBar[13] = { 204*13, 0, 204, 14 };`

Comment: Also - your big if block? `frame = character.characterhealth / 5` seems like it would work just fine.

Comment: If you want to simply make a game (and don't want to learn how to make game engines), it might be a better idea to grab gamemaker or Unreal Development Kit. Because you're newbie you might not know what you're getting yourself into by starting to learn C++.

Answer (score 1):

YOur class does not have "character" field. See for yourself:

```
class HeadsUpDisplay
{
    private:
       int frame;
    public:
       SDL_Rect HealthBar[20];
       SDL_Rect offset;
       void init();
       void render();
};
```

You have `frame`, `HealthBar` and `offset`. Yet in every method you decalred you try to access "character".

> character was an object from another class.

C++ class does not know that another object exists. To access another object, you should either pass it into method by reference or pointer:

```
void HUD::render(Character &character){
    if (character.whatever)
        ....
}

void HUD::render(Character *character){
    if (character->whatever)
        ....
}
```

Or it should be declared as global variable BEFORE function body that tries to access it.

```
Character character;//or extern Character character;

void HUD::render(){
    if (character.whatever)
        ....
}
```

If "character" wasn't mentioned in any form before compiler encounters function body that tries to access character, compiler won't know what "character" is.

It is generally a good idea to avoid using global variables when possible.

Comment: Pass it in as an argument. C++ isn't psychic. `void render(character& the_character)` perhaps?

Comment: @user2949299 if you do not understand something as basic as class declarations and inheritance you should really not be going into developing games yet, you should think simpler first until you get a grasp on the core concepts of c++, otherwise you will be spamming SO with questions every step of the way

Comment: I think it's great people are trying to learn game programming, but I have to be honest that C++ is the hardest path to take. It's a terribly abusive language, enormously complicated, and although unbelievably powerful, takes the better part of a decade to master. I would **strongly** recommend something like [PyGame](http://www.pygame.org/) where you can focus on the fundamentals of game programming rather than C++ idiosyncrasies, or the free version of [Unity](http://unity3d.com/) with C# or JavaScript.

Comment: @MatthewPigram: You don't need classes and inheritance to write games.

Comment: @tadman: You do not need to learn programming to make a game. By learning programming, you'll eventually (few years later) learn how to write engines. And engine is not a game. For somebody who wants to write engines, I'd **strongly** recommend to stay as far away as possible from PyGame and Python. While the language has few decent libraries and easy to start toying with, you'll encounter problems further along the road. C, C++, LISP, maybe Java, and maybe C# will be a more worthwile investment of time. Knowing python won't hurt, but it isn't that great for writing engines.

Comment: It's all a matter of opinion. Python is the scripting engine of a lot of things, like the [Blender Game Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blender_Game_Engine), Maya's internal environment, [Cocos2d](http://cocos2d.org/), and can be used in [Ogre3D](http://python-ogre.org/) as well. Python is more than fast enough to learn with, and for more advanced work, you'd use a pre-existing framework most of the time where Python serves as a very good scripting language for that. Nobody still learning can come even close to making Unity or Ogre3D on their own.

Comment: Besides, if you know Python well enough, you'll be able to pick up C# or Java pretty easily. C++ is a completely different beast.

Comment: @tadman: For scripting, and as a general purpose "duct tape" language, python is good, I won't argue with that (although there's lua for games). By writing a whole game or the whole engine in it is very bad idea. " know Python well enough" If you know C++ well enough, you'll be able to pick almost ANY language easily (maybe with exception of Haskell and Prolog). Besides, that is a weak argument. Once you know  one language, the rest will look pretty similar. It is a good idea to start either with assembler or with something difficult, like C++. Or you could start with something like LISP

Comment: @SigTerm You do if you want to write something even remotely complex, plus it makes extending the codebase much much easier, sure you could just write procedural code but thats really not a good solution here. Also since he is using classes in his code he should know how they work

Comment: @MatthewPigram: A lone programmer is unlikely to write game so complex that it can't be done without classes. Doom/Quake games were written in C.

Comment: Also why steer him away from C++, by learning C++ he will learn some much better programming concepts (which are helpful when making games as) as well as skills that translate to almost any modern language as many use similar constructs present in C++.

Comment: @SigTerm when you have something as nice as classes to better organise your code why would you not use them? It is really doing things the hard way by doing things procedurally and makes coding more difficult and time consuming

Comment: @MatthewPigram: "Also why steer him away from C++" If he wants to make games, be learning how to program is going in the wrong direction. If he wants to make *game engines*, then direction is correct. "why would you not use them" Because just having ability to make classes and inherit can be extremely distracting. "Lets design hierarchy for everything. Oh, let's change it. Oh, let's change it again, and add more operators". For a beginner it can be extremely unproductive timesink - you can delude yourself into thinking that you're doing something useful, while in reality code doesn't improve

Comment: @SigTerm you are basing this on the assumption that he does not want to engine program, no where has he mentioned that is his goal or NOT his goal

Comment: @MatthewPigram: Please go to my previous comment and read **SECOND** sentence. It is here for a reason. Oh, and yes, many young people tend to think that learning programming will allow them to make games, while in reality artists and designers are more important than programmers. So for making games, learning how to draw, model or design levels will be more useful.